# UITableViewCells are displayed outside of the table view container

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller which contains a table view controller embedded in a container view:

[image]

What you see inside the view controller on the left is a container view that embeds the table view controller through a storyboard segue. And like you see in the image, there is also a constraint that specifies a top space between the container view and the above segmented control.

When I launch the application everything is normal and I can see a separation space between the segmented control and the table view cells. But as I scroll down, as you see in the blow picture the table view cells overlap with the segmented control:

[image]

By debugging the view hierarchy I found out that the problem is that the cells are displayed even if they are outside of the container view:

[image]

What you see in the above pictures are the table view cells and the container view. I've drawn two red lines, one starting from the container view top and one starting from the top of the first table view cell and like you see the table view cells go beyond the bounds of the container view, which means that they are visible even if they are outside of the table view area. Instead, the container view which embeds the table view is below the segmented control and the separation space imposed by the constraints is respected.

Comment: Just make sure the tableView’s view constraints are equal to the containerView’s (topAnchor, bottomAnchor, etc) and then set tableView.clipsToBounds = true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try setup `clipsToBounds`? It can be help.

```
tableView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Must be something to do with how you've laid out your constraints. Hard to tell by the pictures.

I set a height constraint to the view that has the segmented control. And set the vertical spacing between that view and the container view to 0.

[image]

I uploaded a demo project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mc0949rlzmakbdj/EmbedTable.zip?dl=0).